# fetch car's from car table with check booking date from booking table, If date is availabel in booking tabel then don't display that perticular car

Tags: php, mysqli

fetch car's from car table with check booking date from booking table, If date is availabel in booking tabel then don't display that perticular car

First tabel name= car:

```
car_id,company,model
```

AND Second tabel name= booking:

```
car_id,booking_date
```

Code

```
<?php 
include "db.php";

//echo $date;(2016-12-21)

$r5=mysqli_query($db,"select * 
                    from booking mrm, car mb 
                    where mrm.car_id=mb.car_id 
                    and booking.DATE(booking_date)=$date");


while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($r5))
{

?><tr>
        <td><?php echo $r['car_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['company']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['model']; ?></td>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No display because your query is syntactically incorrect and will fail.

Comment: **Debugging Basics** Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: @ Pierre-Loup Pagniez 
I want to fetch car record's from car table. But, If car is already booked then this perticular car don't display..

Comment: Uday, have you even red the answer of riggs?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Then what is correct query??

Comment: Well you could try reading a basic SQL tutorial or `and DATE(booking_date) != '$date'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$sq=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM car as c WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM booking as b WHERE c.car_id = b.car_id AND b.drop_date <= '$date' AND b.pickup_date >= '$date')");